# python - array not outputting entire value just character

Tags: python, regex

I would like the code below to output the entire stored value in the array right now it just puts the first character when I'm specifying the next

Desired:

```
['6.1', '6.2', '6.3', '6.4', '6.5']
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
```

Actual:

```
['6.1', '6.2', '6.3', '6.4', '6.5']
6
6
6
6
6
```

Issue:

```
print (idPercentageDetailsArray[0])
```

This is the issue.  I think I'm requesting the array index 0 but I'm instead I'm getting the position 0 of each string. Unclear why.  Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
    import re

    processDetails = """
        Percent Done: 6.1%

        Percent Done: 6.2%

        Percent Done: 6.3%

        Percent Done: 6.4%

      Percent Done: 6.5%"""

    idPercentageDetails = re.findall(r'Percent Done:\s+([0-9]+[.,][0-9]+|[0-9]+)', processDetails, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    print (idPercentageDetails)

    for idPercentageDetailsArray in idPercentageDetails:
        print (idPercentageDetailsArray[0])
```

Comment: Don't you want `print (idPercentageDetailsArray)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the line:

```
print (idPercentageDetailsArray[0])
```

to

```
print (idPercentageDetailsArray)
```

Since the `[0]` means your getting the first character of the ***string***: `idPercentageDetailsArray`

---

You probably want to, therefore, change your variable names to something like this for your code to make more sense:

```
import re

process_details = """
    Percent Done: 6.1%

    Percent Done: 6.2%

    Percent Done: 6.3%

    Percent Done: 6.4%

  Percent Done: 6.5%"""

id_percentage_details = re.findall(r'Percent Done:\s+([0-9]+[.,][0-9]+|[0-9]+)', process_details, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(id_percentage_details)

for id_percentage_value in id_percentage_details:
    print(id_percentage_value)
```

**Output:**

```
['6.1','6.2', '6.3', '6.4', '6.5']
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4
6.5
```